# Resizing a Silverlight or Flash video player?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, video, flash

Is it possible to resize a silverlight/flash video player on the fly?  I would like to create a video where I can drag the bottom left corner to resize the player (maintaining aspect ratio) or at least eliminate the possibility of doing so I could move on to other methods.

Thanks in advance...

EDIT: // forgot to mention
Sorry forgot to mention, this would also mean that the actual video itself resizing right?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, this would also mean that the actual video itself resizing right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Silverlight:**  Absolutely.  Just set the the Stretch property to Uniform and then alter either the Width or Height as you resize.

Answer (score 6):

**Flash:** Yes, you can alter the size of a flash object through JavaScript. Using a YUI, jQuery, or a Mootools JavaScript library, this should not be too difficult to prototype.

[Here is a posts](http://www.dncompute.com/blog/2008/06/23/browsercanvas-the-worlds-easiest-way-to-dynamically-resize-flash.html) which explains how to resize flash from within your flash code.

Proportional resizing - [here is an example of that as well using jQuery](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui/browse_thread/thread/c2e4008f8620a09f/5b6d56c1d4725300).

I'm not sure if the same is true for Silverlight browser objects, although I'd be surprised if you couldn't do the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a CSS solution for [resizing videos on the fly](http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/how-to-resize-videos-on-the-fly.asp).

The video can even resize itself according to the user settings if it is styled using EMs. This demo shows how a [video resize itself according to the width of the user agent](http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/video-resizing/video.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the silverlight scaling. This [photo retouching and restoration](http://www.retouchgenie.com) site has a couple of silverlight controls that scale with browser resizing. There is quite a nice photo gallery that shows the photos before and after the retouch.

Answer (score 0):

**JWPlayer**

As of version 5.3 they added a resize() method to the javascript API which allows you to resize a player - and all the control bar etc. will resize correctly too.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference

> resize(width, height) Resizes the
>   player to the specified dimensions.
>
> width:Number: the new overall width of
>   the player.
>
> height:Number: the new
>   overall height of the player. Note: If
>   a controlbar or playlist is displayed
>   next to the video, the actual video is
>   of course smaller than the overall
>   player.